# Program loading (incorrect) dll even though it is statically linked

Tags: windows, visual-c++, dll

I'm building some thrift code on windows which has the following dependencies:

- open ssl
- thrift

Setup:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- VS2013

Goal:

- 32-bit thrift app

I compiled open ssl using [these instructions](http://p-nand-q.com/programming/windows/building_openssl_with_visual_studio_2013.html) (32-bit release) which produced `libeay32.lib` and `ssleay32.lib`. Next I created a VS2013 project to build the thrift library that depends on open ssl. On compilation, this project produced `libthrift.lib` which is (as far as I can tell) statically linked:

[image]

All good so far...

Next, I build my thrift app., again, linking statically:

[image]

However, when I run my thrift app., I get the following error that complains about incompatible image types (x86/x64):

[image]

To find the cause, I ran dependency walker on my app only to find that it's pulling in 64-bit ssl dlls (!) that came with the 32-bit (!!!) mercurial installation:

[image]

My understanding is that my application should only link against `libthrift.lib` which has already statically linked the open ssl stuff (above).

It seems my understanding is not up to scratch but I'm stumped as to where I'm going wrong...

Comment: The build instructions you linked are for building the DLLs.  So that's what you got.  You forgot to copy the DLLs into your build directory.  You could consider sending a nastygram to the Mercurial team for adding common DLLs to the PATH.

Comment: What setting should I change to link statically so all the code dependent is built into the app?